# Can I delete statements that express thanking from questions?

Tags: discussion, edits, signatures

There are many questions on many Stack Exchange sites that have paragraphs thanking people in advance which may cover a large fraction of the question area and I think it's NOT necessary to express the thanking since the website is for questions and answers and also people who answer the question will receive reputation.

So can I edit posts that have **'thank you'** paragraphs?